# Why can't asterisk triangle be larger than 23?

Tags: c

I'm currently learning C programming and came through one simple exercise.

Refer to this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* nstars(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int sn;
    printf("Number of stars: ");
    scanf("%d", &sn);
    for(int i = 1; i <= sn; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s", nstars(i));
    }
    return 0;
}

char* nstars(int n)
{
    char* starstr = (char*) calloc(n, sizeof(char));
    for(int nt=0; nt < n; nt++)
    {
        starstr[nt] = '*';
    }
    return starstr;
}
```

The above code will print something like this

```
sn=4
*
**
***
****
```

The code is working fine until the `sn` is above 23. It starts printing out strange characters.

Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: No `NUL` character terminator. Should be `calloc(n + 1, ...)` and `starstr[n] = '\0'`;

Comment: What is the point to call calloc if you change `starstr` just after. `int` could be negatif, you should use `size_t` and verify `scanf()` correctly parse the field. Also, you didn't check the validity of `starstr` and you should not cast `void *`.

Comment: Who releases the memory you allocate?

Comment: @FiddlingBits First of all it should possibly be `starstr[n] = '\0'`. But then since the OP is using `calloc` that explicit setting of the terminator is not needed, if the OP remembers the `n + 1`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good observation. `calloc` sets memory to `0`.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to change `n` to unsigned or have `nstars` check for negative input.

Comment: I get it, every string must be terminated by NULL, right? And by using `calloc(n+1, ...)` the last character will always be 0, is this correct?

Comment: The memory you allocated is never freed, it is leaked. It would be better to write a function `print_nstars` where allocation would not be needed at all.

Comment: 'every string must be terminated by NULL' - not every, but yes. 'by using calloc(n+1, ...) the last character will always be 0' - yes and no. The last character will be 0, because calloc zeroes the buffer. Not always, you can overwrite it. The worst part with this code is it never calls `free` on the memory returned by `calloc`. This is bad.

Comment: Every string must be `NUL` terminated or its just a `char` array.

Comment: @Osiris Could you please explain why the unfreed memory can cause a memory leak?

Comment: @Anakin In your function you are allocating space for your string and then return it and directly pass it as parameter to `printf`. After the call to `printf` you no longer know the address of the allocated memory, which means you can neither use or free it.

Comment: @Anakin Unfreed memory to which you no longer have a reference *is* a leak by definition.

Comment: @Osiris Okay, I get it. thanks

Comment: the posted code has a significant memory leak.  On every iteration some memory is being allocated via `calloc()` but that memory is never returned to the heap, via `free()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not properly terminating the `starstr` string - up until you reach size 23, there *just happens* to be a 0-valued byte immediately following the last element of `starstr`, so it looks like it's working properly up to that point.

An n-character string needs to be stored in an array that's *at least* n+1 elements wide to account for the terminator, so you need to adjust your `calloc` call like so:

```
char *starstr = calloc( n + 1, sizeof *starstr );
```

A couple of notes - first, the cast on `calloc` is unnecessary as of C89<sup>1</sup>, and can suppress a useful diagnostic if you're using a C89 compiler<sup>2</sup>.  Second, you can use `sizeof` on your target to get the right type size - the type of the *expression* `*starstr` is `char`, so `sizeof *starstr` is equivalent to `sizeof (char)`.  `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition, so strictly speaking you can replace all that with the literal `1`, but this way if you ever decide to use a "wide" character type like `wchar_t`, you won't have to change the `calloc` call itself.

Finally, as written this code has a fairly nasty memory leak - you're allocating a new array each time you call `nstars`, but you aren't deallocating it when you're done.

Frankly, you shouldn't need to allocate a new array for each line - allocate the array *once* at the final size (+1 to account for the terminator), then add a new asterisk to the end:

```
int main( void )
{
  ...
  char *starstr = calloc( n + 1, sizeof *starstr );

  /**
   * ALWAYS check the result of a malloc, calloc, or realloc call.
   */
  if ( !starstr )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Could not allocate memory for string - exiting\n" );
    exit( 0 );
  }

  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )    // Each time through the loop, add an
  {                                // asterisk to the end of starstr,
    starstr[i] = '*';              // then print starstr.  
    printf( "%s\n", starstr );
  }
  free( starstr );
  ...
}
```

Since `calloc` zeroes out the allocated memory, you don't need to explicitly write a string terminator after you add a new asterisk.  Had you used `malloc` instead, you'd need to write

```
starstr[i] = '*';
starstr[i+1] = 0;
printf( "%s\n", starstr );
```

---

1. It's required in C++, but if you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc`,`calloc`, or `realloc` unless you *really* need to get your hands dirty.

   C89 allowed implicit `int` declarations, so if you forgot to include `stdlib.h` or didn't otherwise have a declaration for `calloc` in scope, the compiler would assume it returned an `int` and would issue a diagnostic if you tried to assign the result to a pointer.  However, if you cast the result to a pointer, then the compiler *wouldn't* issue the diagnostic, and you may have wound up with a runtime error.  C99 and later no longer allow implicit `int` declarations, so this particular issue isn't a problem anymore, but it's still better to leave the cast off.  It makes the code easier to read and easier to maintain.

Comment: Accepted this because of being more clear in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Just put `n + 1` for `calloc`:

And also: don't forget to `free`!

a `char *` MUST end with a '\0' so you need to allocate with the size + 1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* nstars(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int sn;
    printf("Number of stars: ");
    scanf("%d", &sn);
    for(int i = 1; i <= sn; i++)
    {
        char *str = nstars(i);
        printf("\n%s", str);
        free(str);
    }
    return 0;
}

char* nstars(int n)
{
    char* starstr = (char*) calloc(n + 1, sizeof(char));
    for(int nt=0; nt < n; nt++)
    {
        starstr[nt] = '*';
    }
    return starstr;
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that `sizeof(char)` is redundant and unnecessary as a `char` is always one byte.

Comment: and to not cast the result of `*alloc()` in C-code and that `size_t` should be used for the sizes of and indexes into objects.

Comment: That looks like a good solution, but without an explanation of *why* it solves the problem, it's not a very good answer.

Comment: @Swordfish So `(size_t) 8` is different from `(int) 8` in some way?

Comment: As Caleb wrote, I really want the explaination more than the solution

Comment: @Anakin, the big difference is that `size_t` is `unsigned` whereas `int` is `signed`

Comment: *a `char *` MUST end with a '\0'* This is misleading. A C-style *string* must end with a `\0`, but you can have a pointer to `char` where the last byte isn't a null and that's perfectly fine. Pascal-style strings, for example, start with a length byte and have no terminating null. If you're talking about C strings, say that instead of `char *`.

Comment: @TimRandall the type being `signed` or `unsigned` is not the point.

Comment: @Anakin The standard guarantees, that `size_t` is \*big enough\* to hold all possible sizes of objects and indexes into them.

Comment: Okay, I understand it now. Thanks everyone for the nice reply :)